# Python IRC bot: Return nicks in channel

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm trying to have my bot call /NAMES of a certain channel when a command is called, and return a list of everyone voiced. Some help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where is your code? I did this a while ago but since I am not sure about your implementation of the bot I can't help more.

You can send the string "/names #channelname" and the next line you receive will include it. .

Comment: ircsock.send("/names #channelname"\n")

Use ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)
then 
if ircmsg.find(' NAMES ') != -1: do something with names, but I'm not sure about the specific structure of the reply you get when you send names, so figure it out and use it to split accordingly.